# how to get NavLink to observe case sensitivity

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I was wondering how to fix this code to allow for the `NavLink` to observe case sensitivity.  I've added the sensitive props to the `Route` components to no avail.  What i see here is that clicking on either `first` or `second` will cause the active link styling to be enabled for both links when I want only the clicked item to have the styling engaged.  Thanks.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, NavLink, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>Welcome To Example!</h1>
      <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/first">First</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/First">Second</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

const HomePage = () => {
  return <h1>HomePage</h1>;
};
const FirstPage = () => {
  return <h1>FirstPage</h1>;
};
const SecondPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>SecondPage</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" sensitive component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/first" sensitive component={FirstPage} />
        <Route path="/First" sensitive component={SecondPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Have you tried adding location to your switch? <Switch location={history.location}>

Comment: can you elaborate? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Added a more complete explanation, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have never done routes that have capital letters, but I remember having problems with styles. In any case I show you the way I do it in case it works for you.

Routes Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/templates/home';
import Portfolio from './components/templates/portfolio';
import NotFound from './components/templates/notfound';


const Routes = ({ history }) => {
  const { location } = history;
  return (
    // Here we add the location to the switch component
    // It can help with CSSTransition/TransitionGroup
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/portfolio" exact component={Portfolio} />
      <Route path="*" exact component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
};


export default withRouter(Routes);
```

Edit: I figured out that you need to perform some logic to get this working. I made a component that handles this situation.

```
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = ({
  children,
  to,
  exact,
  className,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    path={to}
    exact={exact}
    // Needed to render whether the path matches the location or not. 
    children={({ match }) => (
      <Link
        // Here we compare the matching url with our path
        className={
          match && to === match.url ? `${className} active` : className
        }
        to={to}
        // Here we avoid adding the same route to the history
        replace={match && to === match.url}
      >
        {children}
      </Link>
    )}
  />
);
```

I edited your code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-navlinkactive-zcycw)

Comment: thanks. I just tried that but it looks like I'm getting the same behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-navlinkactive-ec3xu

Comment: @reactor I fixed that situation with a component, edited my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

React Router never know it's `first` or `First` after enabled `sensitive` prop as `true`. Now all links will known as `first`.

But if there is no complex URL as `:dynamic`, you could use simple fix that `className={location.pathname === '/first' && 'active'}` instead of `activeClassName` of **React Router**.

**Your CSS Rule when the `NavLink` active:**

```css
.active
{
  color:red;
}
```

**A simple example:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css'
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';
import Users from './users';
import Contact from './contact';
import Notfound from './notfound';

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink className={location.pathname === '/first' ? 'active' : ''} to="/first">
            Users
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink className={location.pathname === '/First' ? 'active' : ''} to="/First">
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact sensitive path="/" component={App} />
        <Route sensitive path="/users" component={Users} />
        <Route sensitive path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route component={Notfound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: how does this address case sensitivity?

Comment: I've improved details. I hope that helps.